# Call variables in function by adding to variable number?

Tags: python, function, variables, tkinter

I'm Creating a gui in tkinter and have buttons named btn1 btn2 btn3 etc, what i want the button to do on click is disable the button clicked and enable the next button in order. I can write out 6 seperate functions but that seems to defeat the point of a function.

```
    if (btn1['state'] == tk.NORMAL):
        btn1.config(state=tk.DISABLED),
        btn2.config(state=tk.NORMAL)

    else: print ('already clicked')
```

this is what i have now, but i want it to look more like btn #+1 (state=DISABLED)

Comment: You don't need the `else`. If a `Button` is disabled it will not call it's command when clicked. Which means you also don't need the `if`. If the command is called then the state must be normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the buttons in a list, and then iterate over the list.

Here's a bit of a contrived example:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

def click(button_number):
    button = buttons[button_number]
    button.configure(state="disabled")
    if button == buttons[-1]:
        # user clicked the last button
        label.configure(text="BOOM!")
    else:
        next_button = buttons[button_number+1]
        next_button.configure(state="normal")
        next_button.focus_set()

label = tk.Label(root, text="")
label.pack(side="bottom", fill="x")

buttons = []
for i in range(10):
    state = "normal" if i == 0 else "disabled"
    button = tk.Button(root, text=i+1, state=state, width=4,
                       command=lambda button_number=i: click(button_number))
    button.pack(side="left")
    buttons.append(button)


buttons[0].focus_set()
root.mainloop()
```